# NULL return when calling a Python function from a C extension

Tags: python, c

I am calling a function in a Python module from a C extension using the method suggested in the 2.7 tutorial.  Here is my code in the C extension:

```
    result = PyObject_CallObject(pFailureFormatFn, failureObj);
    if (result)
    {   // We got a good result from the function
        if (PyArg_ParseTuple(result, "OO", &resultDict, &resultString))
        {   // Decode success
            < snip >

            Py_DECREF(resultDict);
            Py_DECREF(resultString);
        }

        Py_DECREF(result);
    }
    else
    {   // Bad result from the function
        logEvent("The call to pFailureFormatFn returned a NULL result");
        PyErr_Clear();
    }
```

I find that this call returns good results for a number of invocations and then it starts returning NULL for all invocations until the program exits.  The function, in the Python domain (call it funcA), that is being called calls another function that calls itself recursively (call that function funcB).  I have determined that the problem occurs in funcB.

My question is how can I find out what the problem in funcB is?  I have used gdb to run the program and nothing bad happens in there.  That is, the NULL result is returned and execution continues.  I want to figure out what is causing the NULL return (can I see the Python stack trace?).

Comment: Can you add the definition of `pFailureFormatFn`, as well as `funcA` and `funcB`? That would make it easier to answer your question, thanks!

Comment: pFailureFormatFn points to funcA and it looks like this:

    decode = dict()
    if timestamp != None:
        decode['time'] = timestamp

    if context != None:
        decode['context'] = context

    if devApi != None:
        api = devApi >> 24
        decode['actionProvider'] = api, nebula.DecodeApi(api)
        decode['devHandle'] = devApi

    elif failure == Failure.CHECKSUM_ERROR:
        decode['desc'] = failureInfo

    result = Hexify(((failure, Failure._failureDesc.get(failure, 'Undefined')), decode))

    return result, pprint.pformat(result)